# Searching a Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers

Below I have a linked list with a search function. This function not only searches for an element in the list, but also set the previous Node's address, which will later be used in a delete function. If the value is found in the list, the node's address will be returned, otherwise the previous node is null and the function returns null. I am receiving a segmentation fault and I am unsure why. Can someone explain to me why? Thanks.

```
struct IntNodeType {
   int value;
   IntNodeType * next;

   IntNodeType (int v=0, IntNodeType * p=NULL):value(v),next(p)
   {

   }
};

IntNodeType * Search (IntNodeType * firstNodePtr, int value,
                IntNodeType * & prevNode)
{

        IntNodeType * cur;
        IntNodeType * prev;

        cur = firstNodePtr;
        prev = prevNode;

        while (cur!=NULL)
        {
                if (cur->value==value)
                {
                        prev -> next = cur;
                        return cur;
                }
                cur = cur->next; //update p with the current node's next field
        }

        prevNode = NULL;
        return NULL;

}
```

Comment: It seems very strange that your search function modifies the list. Are you sure about your design?

Comment: `prev -> next = cur;` is potentially a problem. There is no check to make sure that `prev` is not `NULL`. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 cases for this function:

1. The value you are trying to find is in the first node and this can be tested using a simple if statement`if(curr->value==value){return curr;}`. This case is not what is required here I guess because it has no previous node pointing to it, unless stated otherwise in the question.
2. The value is in the middle of the list. In this case you should declare two pointers which you did, however, the prev pointer should point to the first node and the curr should point to pre->next `curr=pre->next`. Now in the loop if the value is found `return curr;` else move each pointer to the next node `pre=pre->next` and `curr=curr->next`.
3. The value is not found and this is correctly executed in your code.

Now back to your code. You should have made sure that the pre node is not set to NULL because that would cause an error when trying to set its next node. Moreover, both pre and curr should be traversed simultaneously so you don't lose connection between nodes when setting the `pre->next`.